# Is the following series convergent $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following series convergent  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n}$

I tried everything, nothing appears to work.

can some one give an idea

Comment: I guess so. Note that num < or equal to deno.

Answer (score 10):

Hint $2^n+3^n\leq 2\cdot 3^n$, hence your sum is bounded by
$$\sum_{n} \frac{2\cdot 3^n}{4^n}...$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Comparison or Limit Comparison test with respect to the series $\sum\limits_{n=1} ^\infty (\frac{3}{4})^n$ because the limit

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle{\frac{\frac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n}}{\frac{3^n}{4^n}}}=1\neq0,+\infty$, by force-factoring $12^n$.

Therefore your (positive-term) series behaves exactly as the geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=1} ^\infty (\frac{3}{4})^n$ whose ratio is between $-1$ and $1$ so both are (absolutely) convergent.

P.S. This method can be used in general, even in the cases where an inequality is not available such as $\sum\limits_{n=1} ^\infty \frac{2^n+4^n}{2^n+3^n}$